# i have an issue with my code again and it wont work in VB.net (Exception Unhandled)

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim area As Integer
    Dim gauge As String
    Dim cost As Decimal
    Dim Length, Width, Depth, CostNo As Decimal
    Dim CostNa, combo As String
    Dim ErrorFlag As Boolean
    Dim D1 As String
    Private Sub Area2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Area2.Click
        Length = txtLength.Text
        Width = txtWidth.Text
        Depth = txtDepth.Text
        CostNo = CostumerNo.Text
        CostNa = CostumerName.Text


        ErrorFlag = ErrorLook(Width, Length, Depth)
        If ErrorFlag = False Then
            MsgBox("Invalid")
            Reset()
            txtDepth.Text = ""
            txtLength.Text = ""
            txtWidth.Text = ""
            CostumerName.Text = ""
            CostumerNo.Text = ""
            Result.Text = ""
            output.Text = ""
            A2.Text = ""
            G1.Text = ""
            C1.Text = ""
        ElseIf ErrorFlag = True Then
            MsgBox("u Good")


        End If
        Length = L(Width)
        Width = W(Length)
        A2.Text = a(Width, Length)
        G1.Text = g(gauge)
        C1.Text = c(cost)

        FileOpen(1, "Info1.txt", OpenMode.Append)
        PrintLine(1, Result.Text & " " & CostumerName.Text & " " & CostumerNo.Text & " " & A2.Text & " " & G1.Text & " " & C1.Text)
        FileClose(1)



        FileOpen(1, "Info1.Text", OpenMode.Input)
        While Not EOF(1)
            Result.Text = LineInput(1)
        End While


    End Sub



    Function combo1() As String

    End Function
    Const Cost1 As Decimal = 1.12
    Const Cost2 As Decimal = 1.76
    Public Function c(ByVal cost As Decimal) As String
        If G1.Text = "Gauge1" Then
            Return A2.Text * Cost1
        Else
            Return A2.Text * Cost2
        End If
    End Function

    Public Function g(ByVal gauge As String) As String
        If A2.Text <= 100 Then
            Return "Gauge1"
        Else
            Return "Gauge2"
        End If
    End Function
    'sets the boundaries for the input values
    Public Function ErrorLook(ByVal w As Decimal, ByVal l As Decimal, ByVal d As Decimal) As Boolean
        If l < 1 Or l > 10 Then
            Return False
        Else
            Return True
        End If
        If w < 1 Or w > 10 Then
            Return False
        Else
            Return True
        End If
        If d < 1 Or d > 10 Then
            Return False
        Else
            Return True
        End If

    End Function



    'calculates the width
    Public Function L(ByVal W As Decimal) As Decimal
        Width = txtWidth.Text + (2 * txtDepth.Text)
        Return Width
    End Function
    'calculates the length
    Public Function W(ByVal L As Decimal) As Decimal
        Length = txtLength.Text + (2 * txtDepth.Text)
        Return Length
    End Function
    'calculates the area
    Public Function a(ByVal w As Decimal, ByVal l As Decimal) As Decimal
        Dim area2 As Decimal
        area2 = w * l
        Return area2
    End Function
    'displays the date and time of the system it is eing run from
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        lbTime.Text = Now()
    End Sub

    'the clear button for clearing all of the fields
    Private Sub CA_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CA.Click
        Reset()
        txtDepth.Text = ""
        txtLength.Text = ""
        txtWidth.Text = ""
        CostumerName.Text = ""
        CostumerNo.Text = ""
        Result.Text = ""
        A2.Text = ""
        G1.Text = ""
        C1.Text = ""
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Dumping all your code and telling us it doesn't work is all but useless. Please learn [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) here. Please also learn how to debug. If you haven't set a breakpoint and stepped through your code then it's too soon to post a question here.

Comment: FileOpen(1, "Info1.Text", OpenMode.Input)
        While Not EOF(1)
            Result.Text = LineInput(1)
        End While

Comment: that section comes with an Exception Unhandeled when i execute the code and i have also done the steps you have suggested and done a lot of trial an error already :)

Comment: Your file is called `Info1.Text`?

Comment: Put a Try Catch around the fileOpen code and trap the error.  EX: `Try FileOpen(1, "Info1.Text", OpenMode.Input)         While Not EOF(1)
            Result.Text = LineInput(1)
        End While Catch ex As Exception Dim MyMessqage as String = ex.Message  End Try`  the exact error will me in ex..Message, it'll give you a better idea about whats going on.

Comment: That sounds like VB6 code. If you want to read and write text files in VB.NET then use a `StreamReader` and a `StreamWriter`.

Answer (score -1):

Look at the 'ErrorLook' function. The first thing it does is a boolean test where it will return true or false. Why have you got "If w < 1" e.t.c or "If d < 1" e.t.c, it will never get to them..... I could go on.....
You're obtaining strings into decimals without checking... You're doing calculations on strings without knowing if they are numbers...
Think what it is you are trying to do. First thing, stop using VB6 code and try and understand the logic, maybe you need to start from scratch.